# Project that i started in VS2017 wont build on VS2019: error CS1061

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

project I started in `visual studio 2017` gets this error when I try to run it in `visual studio 2019`:

> Error  CS1061  'SimpleViewWindow' does not contain a definition for
>   'ConnectRDP_Clicked' and no accessible extension method
>   'ConnectRDP_Clicked' accepting a first argument of type
>   'SimpleViewWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?) VPN_Switch 
>   C:\Users\Tommy\source\repos\Soft
>   VPN\VPN_Switch\Windows\SimpleViewWindow.xaml

this error occurs on about 11 other buttons as well.

I have checked that if I add a new event for the buttons that have this error, it does add the new event handler to the `mainwindow.xaml.cs` as it should.

I have also tried to rebuild as other solutions suggested.

XAML

```
<MenuItem Header="File">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=ButtonClickAction}" Click="Connect_Clicked" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Connect to PC" Click="ConnectRDP_Clicked" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="EditVPN_Clicked" />
                        <Separator />
                        <MenuItem Header="New"   Click="NewEntry_Clicked" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Import" Foreground="#FF999999" />
                        <Separator />
                        <MenuItem Header="Create Shortcut" Foreground="#FF999999" />
                        <Separator />
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="Remove_Clicked" />                        
                        <Separator />
                        <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="Exit_Clicked" />
                    </MenuItem>
```

C#

```
private void Connect_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dg_DataGrid.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ConnectionHandeler((VPN)dg_DataGrid.SelectedItem);
    }
}

private void ConnectRDP_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      ConnectRDP();
}

private void EditVPN_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      EditVPNWindow E_Window = new EditVPNWindow();
      E_Window.Show();
}

private void NewEntry_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     AddVPNWindow window = new AddVPNWindow();
     window.Show();
}
```

when running the program on `VS 2017` it works as it should, so I expect it to be some problem with `visual studio 2019`, some path that isn't correct or something like that.

Comment: Did you try to clean the complete solution (via context menu)? Delete all bin + obj folders and then try a rebuild.

Comment: @TorbenSchramme  Cleanup and rebuild of solution results in the same errors unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem on my own. was a simple case of temporary blindness.
the problem was that i have the same toolbar on another window and that window did not have the methods for the buttons like it had in mainwindow. 
Sorry for wasting peoples time :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing `private void ConnectRDP_Clicked` to `protected void ConnectRDP_Clicked`. You may do this for all similar event handlers.